# How can I create a directory tree using C#?

Tags: c#, dependencies

I am going to try to describe what I am trying to do as best I can :)
So I have a text file that contains a bunch of information of components which I will parse through. Next I want to go to the location of each component in the first text file and see what they depend on. Essentially I want to create a directory tree.

```
Example:
FileA depends on
    comp1
    comp2
    comp3
```

After parsing I now have 3 components that FileA depends on. Next I want to go through each of these components and see who depends on them. In the end I would end up with something like:

```
FileA
comp1
    FileB
    comp1a
    comp2a
        FileC
        comp1b
comp2
comp3
```

FileA depends on comp1, comp2, comp3. The fist dependency comp1 has its dependencies in FileB which depends on comp1a & comp2a. comp2a depends on comp1b which is shown in FileC

This is what I have so far to parse the first text file

```
public class readTXT
{
    private string _path;

    public string Path
    {
        get { return _path; }
        set { _path = value; }
    }

    public void parseTXT(string path)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
        int lineNumber = 0;
        int numberOfDependencies = 0;
        string line;
        List<string> depends = new List<string>();


        while ( (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null )
        {
            // look for dependencies
            string contains = "comp";
            string component;
            string[] components;

            if (line.Contains(contains.ToLower()))
            {
                numberOfDependencies++;
                components = line.Split('=',':');
                component = components[1];
            }

            lineNumber++;
        }

        reader.Close();

        foreach (string location in depends)
        {
            depends = new List<string>();
            parseTXT(location);
        }
    }
}
```

Example of contents in files:

```
FileA.txt
comp=javalibaries
comp=graphics
comp=apache

javalibraries.txt (FileB.txt)
comp=json
comp=regex

json.txt (FileC.txt)
comp=javascriptstuff
```

Comment: Can `comp1b` be dependant on `FileA`?

Comment: Hi Bernd. No it cant :(

Comment: Is the first block what the actual file looks like?  Can you show some data from the files so we can see how they files are related to each other?

Comment: Hi Idle_Mind. I have added a little bit of what the files look like at the end of the original question. So if FileA.txt has a component called 'javalibaries' then I want to go to the 'javalibrary.txt' to see what it depends on, and since it depends on 'json' then from there go to 'json.txt' since it is a dependent component, and so on.

Comment: Do you really need to invent a file format? Why you don't use XML or JSON for this?...

Comment: What kind of project are you working in (WinForms, WebForms, WPF)?...and how you do plan on using the Tree?  Do you need to visually represent it?...or simply use it internally for some other programming task?

Comment: Its a WinForm app. Could also be a console app. No I dont need to visually represent it. I just wanted to output the dependencies in a txt document internally.